# How to use CatalogResolver in JAXB

Tags: jaxb, catalog

Here is a method to do that, but I'm not sure if it is a reasonable way.

```
  final SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
  CatalogManager.getStaticManager().setIgnoreMissingProperties(true);
  final CatalogResolver entityResolver = new CatalogResolver(true); 
  try {
    entityResolver.getCatalog().parseCatalog(new URL("file:///catalog.cat"));
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } 

  sf.setResourceResolver(new LSResourceResolver() {
    @Override
    public LSInput resolveResource(String type, String namespaceURI, String publicId, String systemId, String baseURI) {
      if (publicId == null) {
        publicId = namespaceURI;
      }
      return new LSInputSAXWrapper(entityResolver.resolveEntity(publicId, systemId));
    }
  });
```